# how to run arquillian test with gradle in intellij,how to set the build.gradle file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss, build.gradle, jboss-arquillian

I am working on creating arquillian junit tests on intellij with gradle now. Does anyone can tell me how to set the build.gradle file and plugin the arquillian in intellij? There are many tutorials I find just tell how to set the pom.xml file but we dont use that, we use gradle.

Answer (score 2):

Please see an example at https://github.com/mmatloka/arquillian-gradle-sample . Some additional description is here https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver#gradle-importer .